# Convert geographic coordinates to positive pixel coordinates in a north up image

Tags: gdal, rasterio

I have a box with the following coordinates in EPSG:32617

```
geom = [(542101.7620563037, 4136885.0), (542101.7620563037, 4136889.6473684204), (542107.5299877602, 4136889.6473684204), (542107.5299877602, 4136885.0)]
```

Given the affine transform

```
tfm = Affine(0.1, 0.0, 542091.0,
             0.0, -0.1, 4136884.0)
```

I tried the following method using rasterio but it yields negative coordinates which I understand is caused by the negative pixel height due to it being a north up image.

```
>>> geom_pixel = [rasterio.transform.rowcol(tfm, point[0], point[1]) for point in geom]

>>> geom_pixel
[(-10, 107), (-57, 107), (-57, 165), (-10, 165)]
```

So how can I correctly convert the geographic coordinates of the box to **positive** pixel coordinates?

Comment: I think you need to use the **top** left coordinate in the transform

Comment: Could you elaborate? The transform already contains the top left coordinate (542091.0, 4136884.0) doesn't it?

Comment: maybe the lower left then?